# A grammar riddle

Tags: riddle, word

All in all I could be a metaphor
But my first alone is a silhouette
The second relates to on or _____
My final is human communication

What am I?

Hint:

> Idioms, similes and stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are simply

> A Figure of Speech

All in all I could be a metaphor

> A figure of speech is metaphorical, not literal.

But my first alone is a silhouette

> refers to "figure"

The second relates to on or _____

> ...off --> of

My final is human communication

> which is "speech"

Comment: Hahaha well done